# django search form errors

Tags: python, django, search-form

These views.py and search_form.html works well.
When I submit the form with blank input or with long characters, the error will be shown to me.

views.py:  #works correctly

```
def search(request):
error = False
if 'q' in request.GET:
    q = request.GET['q']
    if not q:
        error = True
    elif len(q) > 20:
        error = True
    else:
        books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return render(request, 'search_results.html',
            {'books': books, 'query': q})
return render(request, 'search_form.html',
    {'error': error})
```

search_form.html: #works correctly

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if error %}
    <p style="color:red;">Please submit a search term 20 characters or shorter</p>
{% endif %}
<form action="/search/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

But when I changed those 2 files into those files below, nothing happened after submitting blank form. No error was raised.

views.py:

```
def search(request):
errors = []
if 'q' in request.GET:
    q = request.GET['q']
    if not q:
        errors.append('Enter a search term.')
    elif len(q) > 20:
        errors.append('Please enter at most 20 characters.')
    else:
        books = Book.objects.filter(title__icontains=q)
        return render(request, 'search_results.html',
            {'books': books, 'query': q})
return render(request, 'search_form.html',
    {'errors': errors})
```

search_form.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
<form action="/search/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="q">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: You are using the `search_form.html` template in both cases. I think in your second scenario you want to use `better_search.html`

Comment: well sorry! I've updated my question. first I used `search_form.html` and for the next time, I edited it to use.

Comment: Your 2nd code works fine for me

Comment: Well yes, you are right. That was a simple mistake, I was changing the function name so was calling an other function. Thanks anyway:)